# Changing div style twice, open and close issue.

Tags: javascript, css, html, styles

So, what i want to do is very basic. I have a `div (#content)` and one menu. Everytime a `li` menu item is clicked, the box should close and reopen with new content. I can open the box, and change content, it just skips close style.

How can i run this 2 functions? or there's an alternative method to do this?

HTML:

`<ul><li onClick="CloseContent();OpenContent();">item1</li><li onClick="CloseContent();OpenContent();">item2</li></ul><div id="content"></div>`

Javascript:

> function OpenContent(){
>                    var el = document.getElementById('content');
>                    el.style.padding = "25px 5px 5px 30px";
>                  el.style.height = "450px";
>                  el.style.width = "900px";
>                  el.style.transition = "width 0.2s linear, height 0.2s linear";
>               }
>               function CloseContent(){
>                  var el = document.getElementById('content');
>                  el.style.padding = "0";
>                  el.style.height = "0px";
>                  el.style.width = "0px";
>               }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try introducing a delay between the execution of both the functions?

Try modifying the code of CloseContent as follows:-

```
function CloseContent(){
  var el = document.getElementById('content');
  el.style.padding = "0";
  el.style.height = "0px";
  el.style.width = "0px";
  setTimeout(OpenContent,500);
}
```

And modify your HTML as follows:-

```
<ul><li onclick="CloseContent()">item1</li><li onclick="CloseContent()">item2</li></ul><div id="content"></div>
```